# Initializing state on dask-distributed workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to do something like

```
resource = MyResource()
def fn(x):
   something = dosemthing(x, resource)
   return something

client = Client()
results = client.map(fn, data)
```

The issue is that `resource` is not serializable and is expensive to construct.
Therefore I would like to construct it once on each worker and be available to be used by `fn`.

How do I do this?
Or is there some other way to make `resource` available on all workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always construct a lazy resource, something like

```
class GiveAResource():
    resource = [None]
    def get_resource(self):
        if self.resource[0] is None:
            self.resource[0] = MyResource()
        return self.resource[0]
```

An instance of this will serialise between processes fine, so you can include it as an input to any function to be executed on workers, and then calling `.get_resource()` on it will get your local expensive resource (which will get remade on any worker which appears later on).

This class would be best defined in a module rather than dynamic code.

There is no locking here, so if several threads ask for the resource at the same time when it has not been needed so far, you will get redundant work.