# Initializing task module global in dask worker using --preload?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I was trying to achieve something similar to these questions ([Initializing state on dask-distributed workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469698/initializing-state-on-dask-distributed-workers), [Setting up Dask worker with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432928/setting-up-dask-worker-with-variable)), where I have a (relatively) large model that I want to pre-initialize on a subset of workers that will accept tasks that require the model. Ideally, I don't want the client machine to even have the model.

My initial attempt, before finding those questions, was to define a `delayed` task in a shared module, `worker_task.model`, and assign a module global variable (e.g. `worker_tasks.model.model`) in the workers' `--preload` script for that task to use; however, this didn't work for some reason - the variable gets set in the preload script, but is still `None` when the task is called.

**init_model_worker.py:**

```
import logging
from uuid import uuid4

from worker_tasks import model


def dask_setup(worker):
    model.model = f'<mock model {uuid4()}>'

    logger = logging.getLogger('distributed')
    logger.warning(f'model = {model.model}')
```

**worker_tasks/model.py:**

```
import logging
import random
from time import sleep
from uuid import uuid4

import dask

model = None


@dask.delayed
def compute_clinical(inp):        
    if model is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Model not initialized.')

    sleep(random.uniform(3, 17))

    return {
        'result': random.choice((True, False)),
        'confidence': random.uniform(0, 1)
        }
```

This is the worker log when I start it and submit something to the scheduler:

```
> dask-worker --preload init_model_worker.py tcp://scheduler:8786 --name model-worker
distributed.utils - INFO - Reload module init_model_worker from .py file                                  
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://172.28.0.4:41743'                         
distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory '/worker-epptq9sh', purging      
distributed.utils - INFO - Reload module init_model_worker from .py file                                  
distributed - WARNING - model = <mock model faa41af0-d925-46ef-91c9-086093d37c71>                   
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:     tcp://172.28.0.4:37973                       
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:     tcp://172.28.0.4:37973                       
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:           172.28.0.4:41743                       
distributed.worker - INFO -              bokeh at:           172.28.0.4:37766                       
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:       tcp://scheduler:8786                       
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------                       
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          4                       
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                    1.93 GB                       
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory:           /worker-mhozo9ru                       
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------                       
distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to:       tcp://scheduler:8786                       
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------                       
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection                                           
distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed                                                      
Function:  compute_clinical                                                                         
args:      ('mock')                                                                                 
kwargs:    {}                                                                                       
Exception: RuntimeError('Model not initialized.')
```

You can see that after reloading the preload script, the `model` is `<mock model faa41af0-d925-46ef-91c9-086093d37c71>`; but when I try to call it from the task, I get `None`.

I will try to implement a solution based on the answers to the other questions, but I have several questions related to worker preload:

1. Why is the model `None` when I call the task, after I assigned it in the preload script?
2. Is it generally recommended to avoid doing things like this in the worker `--preload` script? Is it better to invoke initialization of worker state from the client? *If so, why*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the model variable is bundled into your function immediately by however Python serializes functions.  You might try this instead:

```
@dask.delayed
def compute_clinical(inp):       
    from worker_tasks.model import model

    if model is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Model not initialized.')
```

Or, rather than assign variables to global module scope (which can be difficult to understand in Python), perhaps try assigning it to the worker itself instead.

```
from dask.distributed import get_worker

def dask_setup(worker):
    worker.model = f'<mock model {uuid4()}>'

@dask.delayed
def compute_clinical(inp):       
    if get_worker().model is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Model not initialized.')
```

Comment: Part of me likes the use of `worker` to store this type of context, but another part of me is concerned about polluting the namespace of the object and potential future conflicts, for instance, in case you (the developer) need to add a `model` attribute to the `Worker` class for some reason. Would you be open to adding a `context` attribute to the `Worker` class, as a defined place for users to store user-defined worker config/state? Or perhaps it's enough to just say in the documentation that this attribute will be reserved for the user?

Comment: You can protect yourself with an arbitrarily complex name.  You could make your own `_user_data` attribute or something similar if you like.  I don't think that this practice is common enough to codify it.